# Electrodynamic multipole expansion

Tags: electromagnetism, multipole-expansion, moment

I am reading Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics, and I have a question regarding the electrodynamic [multipole expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) (with page numbers I refer to the 3rd edition). So on page 409, he gives in equation 9.9 the general formula for the expansion of the vector potential:

$$\lim_{kr \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf A (\mathbf x) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{e^{ikr}}{r} \sum_n \frac{(-ik)^n}{n!} \int \mathbf j (\mathbf x' ) (\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf x')^n d^3 x'$$

In the following, he takes the orders $n=0$ and $n=1$ and constructs the vector potential with the "physical" multipole moments, i. e. in order $n=0$ the electric dipole moment and for $n=1$ the electric quadrupole tensor and the magnetic dipole moment. Then on p. 415 he says, that from order $n=2$ upwards, the labor becomes increasingly prohibitive to do this decomposition in physical moments again. Instead, he indicates, that a systematic expansion is much easier (what, of course, I understand).

So I'm wondering now, if this decomposition has ever been done for $n=2$ (to get the electric octupole and the magnetic quadrupole tensor) or even higher orders, and if so, if is there a paper where this sophisticated task has been written down?

Comment: Even where referring to standard literature, it is very helpful for people reading this if you just post the equations you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, I have added the basic equation of the expansion I refer to.

Comment: @TornadoXXL Protip: don't read Jackson

Comment: Why not? Jackson is the standard book of electrodynamics.

Comment: @TornadoXXL because http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm-4PltMB2A

Comment: Lol! Of course I know that one can do the expansion quite simple in spherical coordinates. But this is not the topic here.

Comment: @Yossarian What does that video say? Youtube is blocked here.